How to calculate the graph edge weights when doing arbitrage on Uniswap using Bellman-Ford?
I am trying to create an arbitrage bot on Uniswap by using graph data structure. On this graph nodes represent tokens and edge weights represent the exchange rate between tokens. By applying -log trick to these weights, we are able to benefit from the Bellman-Ford algorithm to find negative cycles on this graph which will indicate an arbitrage opportunity. Keep in mind that I don't care about fees for the sake of the question.
This is one of the main ways arbitrage is suggested to be done on the internet, and there are many articles explaining how to do this in 10 different ways. But there is one thing that I just can not find information on, which is, how do you calculate the exchange rate between tokens? Uniswap uses constant market-maker algorithm, which means that the exchange-rate is actually dependent on the input token amount, meaning its dynamic. So how can I accurately calculate edge weights?

"dependent on the input token amount"  Choose an amount and use that.  Make the amount a run time variable and user can explore whether opportunities appear for certain amounts.

@ravenspoint I want users to be able to find opportunities despite the amount. I know one way to do this is that first find a cycle (using BFT or whatever), second calculate the optimal amount to arbitrage on this cycle (using already existing equations. e.g. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/159056/uniswap-v2-optimal-arbitrage-amount). But I am specifically curious about whether Bellman-Ford can achieve this without input token amount known beforehand.

Depends if your using v2 or v3, if your using v2, the weights should be applied as a function X * Y = K, if your doing v3 you basically need to apply the weights based on the liquidity with in the tick spacing. for all the surrounding ticks, which can be a bit crazy because you need to know exactly how many ticks your swap can affect, or you need to manage the entire tick cache offline (to do it competitively).  Keep in mind that the swap is stateful so you will need to update the reserve balances when quoting.
